# find max value's column index and row index individually in R

Tags: r, max, row

I find people use

```
which(matrix==max(matrix, na.rm=FALSE))
```

to show both row and column index. 
But my question is how do I extract row index and column index individually and then return these two values into another parameters?

like matrix=

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]    3    6    7    7    2    4    3    7    1     4
[2,]    1    9    8    7    2    6   10    9    5     2
[3,]    7   10    8    4   10    5    4    8    4     4
[4,]    4    3    1    1    3    3    9    7    4     2
[5,]    1    8    1    9    9    8    1    3    7     7
[6,]    2    6    7    5    6   10    4    6   15     1
```

the max value is matrix[6,9]=15   how could I find row =6 and column = 9 separately and return 6 to a parameter:A, 9 to parameter:B
Thank you guys very much.

Comment: Just use `d=which(matrix==max(matrix, na.rm=F),T); rowmax=c(d)[1];colmax=c(d)[1]`

Comment: I think it should be colmax=c(d)[2]  ?  Thank you very much.

Comment: You are right about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a large matrix `which.max` should be more efficient than `which`. So, for a matrix `m`, we can use

```
A = row(m)[d <- which.max(m)]
B = col(m)[d]
```

Comment: This code works. but when I type print(which.max(m)), the output is 99 and d is 99 as well...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a roundabout way but if the matrix is called "mat":

```
colmax <- {which(mat == max(mat)) %/% nrow(mat)} + 1
rowmax <- which(mat == max(mat)) %% nrow(mat)
```